# Como fazer divisão de itens a cada X itens

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o PHP para receber os dados do servidor porém quero fazer com que a cada 7 itens a div seja fechada e abra uma nova porém não estou conseguindo.

Exemplo:

```
<div class='grupo'>
    <item>
    <item>
    <item>
    <item>
    <item>
    <item>
    <item>
</div>
<div class='grupo'>
.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar um `foreach`, dividir o valor da contagem por 7 e capturar o resto da divisão. Caso seja 0, fecha a tag.

Você pode capturar esse valor utilizando `$count % 7 === 0`.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22];

/* Imprime a aberta da tag */
echo '<div class="grupo" style="background:red;margin-bottom:10px">';

$count = 1;

foreach($arr as $value) {

    echo "<p>{$value}</p>";

    /** 
     * Verifica se o número é divisível por 7 e se 
     * a contagem é menor ou igual ao número 
     * de elementos do array
     */
    if ( $count++ % 7 === 0 && count($arr) >= $count ) {
        echo '</div><div class="grupo" style="background:red;margin-bottom:10px">';
    }
}

/* Fecha a tag */
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito eu estava no caminho certo porém de outra forma :D